# Why are the variables in initState not acessible?

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-state

I want to create a TextController in the initState and then dispose of it like a good boy in dispose. But for some reason, the controller is not avaiable outside of the intiState:

```
class _InputFieldEnterThingState extends State<InputFieldEnterThing> {
  @override
  void initState() {

    TextEditingController textController =
        TextEditingController(text: 'placeholder');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

It tells me "textController" is not defined in dispose() ... same, if I try using it in the build method. It's, as if the varialbe is strictly local in initState. I feel I'm missing something super obvious, but cannot find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `textController` is a local variable in the `initState` method, you need to make him global and the `dispose` method will recognize him.

The way to do that:

```
class _InputFieldEnterThingState extends State<InputFieldEnterThing> {
  TextEditingController textController;  // make him global


  @override
  void initState() {
    textController =  // without redefine
        TextEditingController(text: 'placeholder'); 
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! That was ist. I was redeclaring it by reusing TextEditingController in the declaration; I did not know that would have this effect. Thanks! Commenting helped a lot!

Comment: With `null safety` enabled you have to either declare the `textController` nullable by adding `?` or use `late`. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you declared the variable `textController` inside `initState` the variable is only accessible in `initState`. If you want to access `textController` e.g. in dispose, you have to declare it outside the `initState`.

```
class _InputFieldEnterThingState extends State<InputFieldEnterThing> {
      late TextEditingController textController;
     
      @override
      void initState() {
        textController = TextEditingController(text: 'placeholder');
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        textController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
```